# FragmentStatePagerAdapter Error

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am new in android application development and 
when I an trying to use FragmentStatePagerAdapter.

I get an error Like

```
  android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:116)
```

And Code is

```
public class ScreenSlide extends FragmentActivity 
{

private static final int NUM_PAGES = 5;
private ViewPager mPager;
private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_screenslide);
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
    mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
    mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_screen_slide, menu);

    menu.findItem(R.id.action_previous).setEnabled(mPager.getCurrentItem() > 0);

    MenuItem item = menu.add(Menu.NONE, R.id.action_next, Menu.NONE,
            (mPager.getCurrentItem() == mPagerAdapter.getCount() - 1)
                    ? R.string.action_finish
                    : R.string.action_next);
    item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
            return true;

        case R.id.action_previous:
            mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
            return true;

        case R.id.action_next:
            mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return ScreenSlidePageFragment.create(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_PAGES;
    }
}
}
```

and Layout for this code is

```
 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

when i run this program i got an error like

```
 03-25 09:29:30.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2401): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 03-25 09:29:30.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2401): Process: com.example.drawer1, PID: 2401
 03-25 09:29:30.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2401): java.lang.NullPointerException
 03-25 09:29:30.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2401):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:116)
 03-25 09:29:30.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2401):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:832)
 03-25 09:29:30.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2401):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:982)
 03-25 09:29:30.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2401):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
 03-25 09:29:30.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2401):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
 03-25 09:29:30.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2401):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16458)
 03-25 09:29:30.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2401):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
 03-25 09:29:30.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2401):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
 03-25 09:29:30.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2401):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16458)
 03-25 09:29:30.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2401):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
 03-25 09:29:30.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2401):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)
 03-25 09:29:30.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2401):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16458)
 03-25 09:29:30.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2401):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
 03-25 09:29:30.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2401):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
 03-25 09:29:30.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2401):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2289)
 03-25 09:29:30.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2401):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16458)
 03-25 09:29:30.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2401):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1914)
 03-25 09:29:30.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2401):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1111)
 03-25 09:29:30.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2401):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1293)
 03-25 09:29:30.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2401):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:998)
 03-25 09:29:30.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2401):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5582)
 03-25 09:29:30.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2401):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
 03-25 09:29:30.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2401):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
 03-25 09:29:30.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2401):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
 03-25 09:29:30.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2401):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
 03-25 09:29:30.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2401):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
 03-25 09:29:30.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2401):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
 03-25 09:29:30.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2401):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 03-25 09:29:30.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2401):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
 03-25 09:29:30.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2401):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 03-25 09:29:30.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2401):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
 03-25 09:29:30.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2401):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
 03-25 09:29:30.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2401):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
 03-25 09:29:30.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2401):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: Please make sure ScreenSlidePageFragment.create(position) is not null